# sort an object based on value in js

Tags: javascript, sorting, javascript-objects

I want to sort an object which is associative in terms (key, value)
I am able to store the values according to the `key`, but unable to sort them on the basis of `value` using in-built `sort()` functions as in case of associative array.

```
var usernames = {};

username[1] = "ZNAME";
username[2] = "BNAME";
username[3] = "ANAME";
username[4] = "TNAME";
username[5] = "KNAME";
username[5] = "YNAME";

$.each(usernames,function(key, value){
    alert(key + " : " + value);
})
```

Please tell the method to sort with my updated JSFIIDLE

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/8sWS8/)

Comment: Objects have no particular order, you want an array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort an object, you have to make it an array. For example:

```
var usernamesArray = [
    {key:1,username:"ZNAME"},
    {key:2,username:"BNAME"},
    ...
    {key:5,username:"YNAME"}
];
var sortedUsernamesArray=usernamesArray.sort(function(a,b){
    //
    return (a.username>b.username)?1:-1;
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GrD4v/

Note: jQuery is not needed here.

[Edit] There are a couple different ways to build the usernamesArray. A simple one:

```
var usernamesObject = {};
var usernamesArray = [];

usernamesObject[1] = "ZNAME";
usernamesObject[2] = "BNAME";
usernamesObject[3] = "ANAME";
usernamesObject[4] = "TNAME";
usernamesObject[5] = "KNAME";
usernamesObject[6] = "YNAME";

for (var i=1;i<7,i++) {
    usernamesArray.push({key:i,username:usernamesObject[i]});
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you please tell how to iterate over usernames to fetch key and username

Answer (score 1):

```
var username = [];

username[0] = "ZNAME";
username[1] = "BNAME";
username[2] = "ANAME";
username[3] = "TNAME";
username[4] = "KNAME";
username[5] = "YNAME";

username.sort();

$.each(username,function(key, value){
    alert(key + " : " + value);
})
```